# How to save config changes back to App.Config

Tags: c#, app-config, class-library

I am trying to make my logger class library to get a few of its config settings from the actual application's App.Config.

1. Nothing is actually saved. Every time I run the application it sets
   the default values. But I still can reference them during the run.
2. If it is saving the settings to a file I can't find the file.
   Its not app.config or user.config in the bin/Debug/ directories.
3. I run CheckLogSettings every time the program starts.

Here is my Helper Class from the Logger Library:

```
public class SettingsHelper
{
    private static readonly Configuration Config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
            (ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    public static void CheckLogSettings()
    {
        string key;

        key = "LoggingEnabled";
        if (Config?.AppSettings?.Settings?[key]?.Value == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Set Default " + key);
            Config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, true.ToString());
            Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
        }

        key = "MaxLogFileSize";
        if (Config.AppSettings.Settings[key]?.Value == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Set Default " + key);
            Config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, (2*1024*1024).ToString());
            Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
        }

        key = "LogFileName";
        if (Config.AppSettings.Settings[key]?.Value == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Set Default " + key);
            Config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, "AppLog.txt");
            Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
        }
    }

    public static bool GetLoggingEnabled()
    {
        return bool.Parse(Config.AppSettings.Settings["LoggingEnabled"].Value);
    }

    public static long GetMaxLogFileSize()
    {
        return long.Parse(Config.AppSettings.Settings["MaxLogFileSize"].Value);
    }

    public static string GetLogFileName()
    {
        return Config.AppSettings.Settings["LogFileName"].Value;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

snipit from my App.Config:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="LoggingEnabled" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MaxLogFileSize" serializeAs="String">
           <value>2097152</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="LogFileName" serializeAs="String">
           <value>AppLog.txt</value>
        </setting>
    </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Comment: "I am trying to make my logger class library to get a few of its config settings from the actual application's App.Config."  By **design**, a class library will read values from the consuming application's config file.  You don't need to do anything special, just pull the values like you would if it was an application.

Comment: i.e., `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"]` will work from your class library just like it will from an application as long as the values are there.  If they're not there, I think a better design would be to throw an error and let the application address the issue, otherwise you're running the risk of tightly coupling you're class library to the applications that use it, which strikes me as a bit of a questionable design, given that class libraries are intended to be reusable across multiple apps.

Comment: @Tim I cannot access ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxLogFileSize"] from either the Class Library or the Application. I can use Properties.Settings.Default.MaxLogFileSize in the Application but not from the Class Library. See my Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to manually add to the App.Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LoggingEnabled" value="True"/>
    <add key="MaxLogFileSize" value="2097152"/>
    <add key="LogFileName" value="AppLog.txt"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then as Tim pointed out: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"]` will work from your class library.